# JavaScript event.currentTarget vs this

Tags: javascript, this, dom-events

Is there a difference between `event.currentTarget` and `this`? What about performance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `currentTarget` event attribute returns the element whose event listeners triggered the event. This is only particularly useful during capturing and bubbling.

You can also use `this` keyword, but when you use the Microsoft event registration model the `this` keyword doesn’t refer to the HTML element.

Please see following link for more information: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

**Problems of the Microsoft model**

But when you use the Microsoft event registration model the this keyword doesn’t refer to the HTML element. Combined with the lack of a currentTarget–like property in the Microsoft model, this means that if you do

```
element1.attachEvent('onclick',doSomething)
element2.attachEvent('onclick',doSomething)
```

you cannot know which HTML element currently handles the event. This is the most serious problem with the Microsoft event registration model and for me it’s reason enough never to use it, not even in IE/Win only applications.

Note:: it may be,now resolved it

Answer (score 4):

jQuery documentation clearly says, that `event.currentTarget` is equal to `this` in most cases (unless you changing scope manually with `jQuery.proxy` or similar):

> This property will typically be equal to the this of the function.
>
> If you are using `jQuery.proxy` or another form of scope manipulation, `this` will be equal to whatever context you have provided, not `event.currentTarget`

https://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/